# Injectables and non Injecatbles clarification

Tags: magento2

According to the [Magento docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html)

> Injectables can request other injectables in the constructor, but
>   non-injectables cannot request other objects in a constructor

As an example it refers the Product Model
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0.0/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product.php

Checking at the constructor of that class i can see that it requests other objects as well. Can somebody clarify how a non-injectable should be implemented and what classes can request/use?

Answer (score 1):

It's a mistake in documentation. Non-injectables can request other objects in constructor, but it's not recommended because it requires additional logic of serialization/deserialization.

With Magento 2 service contracts approach business entities (they are all non-injectables) do not have business logic so they do not need to request other services (injectables)

Comment: Thanks Anton. That clarifies a bit the things.
But what about factories? I can see that the product object is requesting some factories in the constructor. These are not regarded non-injectables?

Comment: Factories are injectables. They should be used whenever some object needs to create some empty non-injectable object (entity). But as I explained in my post, Product using factories is a legacy approach.